# Value won't assign to array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using the jquery method $(this).html() to get the value of a button.

It works fine when I assign the value to a variable (like `x = $(this).html();`)

But won't work when I try to assign the value to an array (like `expression[1] = $(this).html();`)

A

```
// expression = array();


$(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $(".operator").click(function(){

        expression[0] = $(this).html(); //
        alert(expression[0]);           // Won't work

        // x = $(this).html();          // Works
        // alert(x);                    //


                  });
               });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to test the code online, it is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/m44Tn/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array doesn't exist.
You need to create it first:

```
var expression = [];   //Array literal
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare array something like this

```
var expression = new Array();
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw it. The comment I posted earlier (now edited) was to Shakti Singh

Comment: Don't forget the `var`. You don't want to pollute the global scope.