# Passing Variables in Javascript - Doesnt Execute

Tags: javascript

I have written following code to pass File1 variable to Javascript, but its not executing, and I'm not sure why. When I use alert with File1, it works - but the document.write script is not working. Any help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Order[0]="1";
var Order[2]="2";
var Order[3]="4";
var File1=Order[2]+"/"+Order[0]+"/"+%Order[4];

document.write("<script type='javascript' src=http://abc.com/i_sale_third/10957/'" + File1 + ">";

</script>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Can you state what you would like to happen more explicitly?

Comment: The order variables i am going to get from some other JS.. i want to Pass it to the JAvascript tracker code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you did mess up your single quotes in the `document.write`. I fixed it in this, see if it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Order[0]="1";
var Order[2]="2";
var Order[3]="4";
var File1=Order[2]+"/"+Order[0]+"/"+%Order[4];

document.write("<script type='javascript' src='http://abc.com/i_sale_third/10957/" + File1 + "'>";

</script>
```

#### Edits. Try the following code.

Maybe the little `%` is messing it up too right before `Order[4]` (and beside the fact that you may not have defined `Order[4]`). I also added the console.log to your code so open up your console (in Chrome and Safari it is dev tools). You also didn't need to repeat `var` keyword (you can separate them by commas if you didn't know) and according to @ajax333221 (and me) you need to initialize `Order` by doing `Order = []`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Order = [],
    Order[0] = "1",
    Order[2] = "2",
    Order[3] = "4",
    File1 = Order[2] + "/" + Order[0] + "/" + Order[3]; // I think you meant Order[3] not Order[4] here

if(console) console.log(File1); // this will print File1 into the console so you can see the string output

document.write("<script type='javascript' src='http://abc.com/i_sale_third/10957/" + File1 + "'></script>");
</script>
```

Comment: A single quote is missing as Nathan pointed out and maybe this is not th case but is Order[4] defined? Also add a console.log to show the value of File. Then check if that file exists by prepending 'http://abc.com/i_sale_third/10957/'to it and paste it in the browser URL to see if that file loads.

Comment: @saganbyte and also there was another single quote messed up, it was right before `" + File1 +` so the rest was getting cut off in the HTML output when the browser renders it.

Comment: I also wonder what the `%` thing is there for right before `Order[4]`.

Comment: Also why is 'var' repeated for every 'Order[]'

Comment: also as far as I know, you need to initialize the array first `var Order=[]` before you can do any `Order[0]="x";`

Comment: @ajax333221 Yeah I updated my answer with all that. Hopefully that'll work for them.

Comment: "); is missing at the very end

Comment: @Nathan you sneakily added `></script>` like my answer :(, well I forgive you because I also sneakily added the console.log thing by mistake

Comment: @ajax333221 Yeah but it was needed anyway (I didn't really copy it since I noticed that I forgot it.) I upped your answer though since it is still good :)

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Order = []; //created the array
    Order[0] = "1";
    Order[2] = "2";
    Order[3] = "4";

    var File1 = Order[2] + "/" + Order[0] + "/" + Order[3]; //added var and changed Order[3]

    document.write("<script type='javascript' src='http://abc.com/i_sale_third/10957/" + File1 + "'></script>"); //fixed quotes placement and closed with </script>
</script>
```

Useful links to read:

- [Creating an array first solves problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669245/908879)
- [How to close `<script>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Comment: You don't need the `var` keyword on `File1` since you can define them all with the same `var` keyword but separating with commas. Isn't this just a copy of my answer [kinda]? ;) And you can't end `<script>` with `/>` as far as I know.

Comment: @Nathan it is not a copy, my differs a lot. I used `;` after every `Order[x]=x` (while you used commas), I closed properly `document.close()` and other major improvements. About the `/>` I think you are right

Comment: Oh yeah that's an error on my side I forgot that when you use commas, it is really putting `var` in front of all them.

Comment: I've never heard of `document.close()`, what is the purpose of it?

Comment: @Nathan I remember I once read about it on stackoverflow, but for now the only link I can provide is this http://javascript.gakaa.com/document-close-4-0-5-.aspx

Comment: `document.close()` is only when replacing the whole content: _If a script uses document.write( ) or document.writeln( ) to generate **all-new content for a window or frame**, you must append a document.close( ) method to make sure the entire content is written to the document._